# Adding a custom field and renaming header text

Tags: custom-field, header-bar

1. can i add custom field in salesforce like as on image? Not visualforce page[image: Not visualforce page]

2.Can i rename header name in custom object form?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The questions you're asking seem a little vague but if I understand you correctly:

> can i add custom field in salesforce

Yes. Although if you're referring to documents as per your image Salesforce already supports that as standard both assigned to a record and a Documents object to 'dump' other documents.

On Custom Objects, during it's creation you'll be asked whether or not you want to be able to attach files and folders to records.

Otheriwse you have the following options to select from when creating a Custom Field:

[image]

> Can i rename header name in custom object form?

Yes, we've done this on our own Organisation too where we renamed the "Accounts" object to "Companies". However, when writing custom classes, the API name to query this doesn't change. You'd still need to do something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 20
```

But this will still generate the same outcome.